# d3.js - Force-Layout boundary issue V4

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

Currently I am working one of FCC's project [National Contiguity](https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/show-national-contiguity-with-a-force-directed-graph)

Essentially I was able to figure it out how to render the flags sprites and connect the nodes and its links.

The only thing that I am having trouble is implementing is how to behave similar to FCC's [example](https://codepen.io/FreeCodeCamp/full/xVopBo/). Specifically I am trying ways to have the nodes to repel away from the boundries like in the example.

However, mine doesn't behave that way (in fact, it's very clustered but I don't know exactly what properties in the [d3.js Force Documents V4](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/README.md) I should look into). Instead, it seems that though the node and the links stops near the boundary, it stops at that point

```
const width = w - (margin.left + margin.right);
const height = h - (margin.top + margin.bottom);

let flagNodes = d3.select("#canvas")
                  .append("div")
                  .classed("flag-nodes",true)


let svg = d3.select("#canvas")
              .append("svg")
              .attr("id","chart")
              .attr("width", w)
              .attr("height", h)


let chart = svg.append("g")
                .classed("display", true)
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

let simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d,i) {
      return i;
    }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-60).distanceMax(50).distanceMin(5))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width/2, height/2))
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide().radius(35))
    // .force("centering", d3.forceCenter(,height))
    // .force("position", d3.forceX(0).strength(.01))
    // .force("position", d3.forceY(-18))


let link = chart.append("g")
        .classed("links",true)
        .selectAll("line")
        .data(data.links)
        .enter()
          .append("line")

simulation
    .nodes(data.nodes)
    .on("tick", ticked);

simulation
    .force("link")
    .links(data.links);

let node = flagNodes.selectAll(".flag-nodes")
        .data(data.nodes)
        .enter()
          .append("div")
          .attr("class", function(d,i){
            return `flag flag-${d.code}`
          })
          .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended)
        )

node.append("title")
.text(function(d) { return d.country; });

d3.forceX(width)

//functions provided by D3.js
//
function ticked() {
    node
        .style("left", function(d) {
          let xlimit = Math.max(radius, Math.min(width - radius, d.x))
          return (xlimit) + 'px'
        })
        .style("top", function(d) {
          let ylimit = Math.max(radius, Math.min(height - radius, d.y))
          return (ylimit - 2) + 'px'
        });
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) {
          let x1 = Math.max(radius, Math.min(width - radius, d.source.x))
          return x1;
        })
        .attr("y1", function(d) {
          let y1 = Math.max(radius, Math.min(height - radius, d.source.y))
          return y1
        })
        .attr("x2", function(d) {
          let x2 = Math.max(radius, Math.min(width - radius, d.target.x))
          return x2;
        })
        .attr("y2", function(d) {
          let y2 = Math.max(radius, Math.min(height - radius, d.target.y))
          return y2
        });
  }

function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/neotriz/pen/jrYvjJ?editors=1010)

Answer (score 1):

On every tick, run this function on the simulation's nodes:

```
fixBounds() {
    const graphNodes = this.forceSimulation.nodes();

    graphNodes.forEach((node) => {
        if (node.x - this.nodeRadius < 0) {
            node.x = this.nodeRadius;
            node.vx = 0;
        }

        if (node.y - this.nodeRadius < 0) {
            node.y = this.nodeRadius;
            node.vy = 0;
        }

        if (this.width && node.x + this.nodeRadius > this.width) {
            node.x = this.width - this.nodeRadius;
            node.vx = 0;
        }

        if (this.height && node.y + this.nodeRadius > this.height) {
            node.y = this.height - this.nodeRadius;
            node.yx = 0;
        }
    })
}
```

This will cause the nodes to get stuck on the border, and the forces between the nodes will cause them to move away from the border.