# Is a node barrier possible with d3 force layout?

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

Hi I am new to D3 and I can't find any examples a d3 force layout that has barriers which are paths. I am thinking something like this.

[Hour glass of circle nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rA9W7.png)

like this but irregular boundary, not a box.
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1129492

Comment: Related (D3 V4) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39928306/d3-js-force-layout-boundary-issue-v4 are you looking to do this on a specific version of D3 ?

Comment: This might be helpful too : detect if point is in a polygon https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279165/how-to-find-if-point-is-inside-polygon-in-d3-js

Comment: I was looking to do it in v4 and was thinking that maybe one of the nodes could ignore forces and be placed specifically and give off a negative charge, repelling the other nodes.

Answer (score -2):

I don't see why it's not possible, the code used in the example:

```
function tick() {
node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(radius, Math.min(width - radius, d.x)); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(radius, Math.min(height - radius, d.y)); });
```

simply sets maximum and minimum values for the centre of the nodes (cx and cy). So if you can write an equation that represents the shape of the edge you want to create, you should be able to contain the nodes within that shape.

The difficulty might be in mirroring the shape on the other side of the svg.

Something like:

```
function tick() {
node.attr("cx", function(d) { return function(d){ 
d.x = Math.max(radius, Math.min(d3.select(this).attr("cy")- radius, d.x)); }}
.attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(radius, Math.min(height - radius, d.y)))
}
```

I think that should set up a diagonal line on the right hand side with a 1:1 gradient but obviously not tested and it might massively slow down the force.